# Routing in AngularJS is not working. '.config' keyword is not identified

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I have used routing in AngularJS in one of the applications. It is working fine and `.config` is highlighted by webstorm as shown below. It is able to identify the command/keyword.

It is shown as 
'`Non Executed Operation Store'`

But when I tried to use the same `.config` in the other project, it is not working and I checked the libraries and every other steps required multiple times but could not find any difference except this `.config` is highlighted in one and not identified in the other project.

In the second project, it is shown as:

```
'Unresolved function or method config'
```

What might be the probable reasons for this difference in these two??

Comment: may be `angular routing` is not loaded there somehow. you can check in the network tab of the chrome. or may be dependency js files not matching properly.

Comment: Same angular versions?

Comment: check the angular version if its 1.2.x then add ngRoute .

Comment: can you show us the output in your browser and any errors. Webstorm highlighting is only a symptom. We'll need to see the code in context to be able to help

Comment: var jobApplications = angular.module('jobApplications', ['ngRoute']);

jobApplications.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'public/partials/home.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
});

Comment: One more change is the version of Express() am using is different. I am not sure what is wrong with this. Any reference related to this will be helpful..